# Xcode 9 simulator MobileSMS application crashes

Tags: ios, simulator, xcode9, imessage-extension

I decided to upgrade one application of mine to be universal.
On devices everything works fine, but I'm experiencing problems trying to get screenshots (for app submission) from the iMessage extension built within the application.
Once I launch the extension I receive a crash `MobileSMS application crashes`, trying to debug it seems that is crashing due to an `IndexPath` exception, fun fact I'm not using collection views or table views or any `IndexPath`.
As I said on devices works completely fine, but I'm not able to complete the submission process since I do not possess an iPad 12" and its screenshots are required.
Has anyone experiences this issue and found a workaround?
I'm using the last Xcode version (9.0.1)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84700?sr=stream) thread in the Apple Developer forums. Seems to be happening to a lot of people lately.

Comment: Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920916/sticker-pack-crashes-imessage-on-simulator-but-not-on-iphone) has worked for some people.