# Sticker pack crashes iMessage on simulator but not on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Created a sticker pack in Xcode following Apple's online directions and video. All images are correct dimensions and well below file size thresholds.

If I build and run the sticker pack to my physical iPhone it all works flawlessly.

If I build and run the sticker pack on simulator, to any simulated iPhone/iPad, iMessages launches, the icon for my sticker pack appears and then iMessage crashes. I receive the system error: "MobileSMS quit unexpectedly."

I'm running Xcode Version 9.0.1 (9A1004) on MacOS High Sierra 10.13. The error generated by Xcode is below. Any and all answers appreciated. *It is important to note I did not write any code for the sticker pack, nor modify the code. It is all generated automatically by Xcode when building the sticker pack project.*

```
2017-10-24 15:06:52.116813-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] [Warning] Splitview controller <UISplitViewControllerClassicImpl: 0x7fb10bf08a40> is expected to have a view controller at index 0 before it's used!
2017-10-24 15:06:52.289111-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
2017-10-24 15:06:52.364078-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] [Application] Restoring application state. isComposingNew=NO  groupID=(null)
2017-10-24 15:06:52.622894-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] [Warning] IMBalloonPluginManager. Did not find any plugin for id com.apple.messages.browser.MorePlugin
2017-10-24 15:06:52.623092-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] [Warning] Could not determine if com.apple.messages.browser.MorePlugin is a recent or favorite!
2017-10-24 15:06:52.623246-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] [Warning] IMBalloonPluginManager. Did not find any plugin for id com.apple.messages.browser.MorePlugin
2017-10-24 15:06:52.911018-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] IMSendProgress: 0x600000278840 (delegate: 0x7fb10be02320, context: 0x7fb10e013800) is updating sending items from (null) to {}. (removed? 0, inserted? 0, forced? 1, hasSendingMessages? 0)
2017-10-24 15:06:52.936630-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] +[CATransaction   synchronize] called within transaction
2017-10-24 15:06:52.936780-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
2017-10-24 15:06:52.936898-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
2017-10-24 15:06:52.951138-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] [Warning] Invalid parameters bundleIdentifier com.apple.siri.parsec.HashtagImagesApp.HashtagImagesExtension serverBag (null)
2017-10-24 15:06:52.954470-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] [Warning] Invalid parameters bundleIdentifier com.apple.icloud.apps.messages.business.extension serverBag (null)
2017-10-24 15:06:52.956249-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] [Warning] Invalid parameters bundleIdentifier com.hifidesign.Tennis-Anyone.StickerPackExtension serverBag (null)
2017-10-24 15:06:52.957857-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] [Warning] Invalid parameters bundleIdentifier com.apple.ActivityMessagesApp.MessagesExtension serverBag (null)
2017-10-24 15:06:52.959717-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] [Warning] IMBalloonPluginManager. Did not find any plugin for id com.apple.messages.browser.MorePlugin
2017-10-24 15:06:52.959925-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] [Warning] Could not determine if com.apple.messages.browser.MorePlugin is a recent or favorite!
2017-10-24 15:06:52.960175-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] [Warning] IMBalloonPluginManager. Did not find any plugin for id com.apple.messages.browser.MorePlugin
objc[2897]: Class _MSMessageExtensionLoadingView is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Messages.framework/Messages (0x130fd28c0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Messages/iMessageBalloons/MSMessageExtensionBalloonPlugin.bundle/MSMessageExtensionBalloonPlugin (0x130f9e0c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2017-10-24 15:06:57.602375-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] [Warning] IMBalloonPluginManager. Did not find any plugin for id com.apple.messages.browser.MorePlugin
2017-10-24 15:06:57.602562-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] [Warning] Could not determine if com.apple.messages.browser.MorePlugin is a recent or favorite!
2017-10-24 15:06:57.602831-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] [Warning] IMBalloonPluginManager. Did not find any plugin for id com.apple.messages.browser.MorePlugin
2017-10-24 15:06:58.888200-0700 MobileSMS[2897:557106] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path: <NSIndexPath: 0x604000437940> {length = 2, path = 0 - 9223372036854775807}'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109a6f1cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108f8bf41 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109ae3b95 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
3   UIKit                               0x0000000106583cd6 -[UICollectionView _contentOffsetForScrollingToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:] + 212
4   UIKit                               0x000000010658474c -[UICollectionView _scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:] + 70
5   ChatKit                             0x00000001080b9311 -[CKBrowserSwitcherViewController(XCODE_DEVELOPMENT_SUPPORT) scrollCollectionViewToPlugin:] + 240
6   ChatKit                             0x0000000108054b0f -[CKChatInputController _launchAppExtensionForDebugging] + 682
7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109a0b07c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109a0b00f ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 63
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109a1220c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001099f6a3b __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 203
11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001099f683b __CFRunLoopRun + 2875
12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001099f5a89 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
13  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010c53f9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
14  UIKit                               0x0000000105aa823c UIApplicationMain + 159
15  MobileSMS                           0x0000000103b7e2b6 MobileSMS + 135862
16  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010af85d81 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Hi-Fi Guy - did the solution below work for you?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. The solution is to:

1. Close the warning dialog.
2. In the simulator, click on the messages app icon (green speech bubble).
3. Select one of the two people (e.g. Kate Bell).
4. Click on the elipse button icon (...)
5. Click "Edit" button (top right) and then manually enable your sticker pack by tapping the slider switch and turning it on (see screenshot below - the hashtag sticker pack is disabled). Don't forget to tap "Done" when you are finished.

After doing that, the sticker pack works fine - until you relaunch the simulator, then go back to step 1.

[image: The elipse button]

[image: Enable your sticker pack]

Comment: This has been plaguing me. I couldn't figure out how to enable them on my physical device either. Easy upvote.